# Using ProGuard to obfuscate code not working

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my project. When I export using eclipse, I get the following error:

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper$Honeycomb: can't find referenced method 'void setScrollX(int)' in class android.view.View
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper$Honeycomb: can't find referenced method 'void setScrollY(int)' in class android.view.View
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS: can't find referenced method 'long getDuration()' in class android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS: can't find referenced method 'android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator setStartDelay(long)' in class android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS: can't find referenced method 'long getStartDelay()' in class android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS: can't find referenced method 'void start()' in class android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 Warning: com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorICS: can't find referenced method 'void cancel()' in class android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator
 Warning: com.sileria.android.bc.IceCream: can't find referenced method 'void release()' in class android.view.Surface
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(android.view.View,android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)' in class android.widget.AdapterView
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'void appendRecord(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)' in class android.widget.AdapterView
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)' in class android.widget.AdapterView
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'void setScrollable(boolean)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced method 'void setToIndex(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
 Warning: com.sileria.android.view.FriendAdapterView: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 Warning: there were 14 unresolved references to program class members.
          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
          You may need to recompile them and try again.
          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I added the following code in the `proguard-project.txt` but it still not work:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**

-keep class com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.app.** { *; } 
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.nineoldandroids.view.** { *; } 

-keep class com.sileria.android.** { *; } 
-keep interface com.sileria.android.** { *; } 


-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Any idea what I did wrong? and what the right code to add in `proguard-project.txt` for it to work?

Comment: "You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars')." - verify the external libraries (and versions of such) specified.

Comment: how to i do it? i have 4 jars in libs. i need to remove them?